# How to Query Database to Retrive data irrespective of spaces present in Database Record

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi I was recently working on a application where i am supposed to retrieve the data from Database irrespective of number of spaces present between the word i.e.

if the input string from application to database is  **"ChennaiCampus"[WITHOUT ANY SPACES]** but the actual value in the database is **"Chennai Campus"[WITH one or many SPACES IN BETWEEN]** is still should be able to retrieve it.

Currently Iam using the following query

> SELECT CAMPUS_ID FROM CAMPUS WHERE CAMPUS_NAME = ?

Where ? indicates the value provide at the run time from the application.

Comment: be aware that all supplied answers so far would not use any index you might have on the `CAMPUS_NAME` column. Your query might not be very performant if there is a large data set. You could mitigate this by creating a function based index which removed spaces on the `CAMPUS_NAME` column of the `CAMPUS` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAMPUS_ID FROM CAMPUS WHERE replace(CAMPUS_NAME,' ','') = replace(?,' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows even spaces on both sides:

```
SELECT CAMPUS_ID FROM CAMPUS 
WHERE replace(CAMPUS_NAME,' ','') = replace(?,' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 SELECT CAMPUS_ID 
   FROM CAMPUS 
  WHERE replace(CAMPUS_NAME,' ','') = replace(:parameter,' ','') ;
```